# I am trying to use filter function with a nested list but I am not able to store the 0'th element of the inner list by using the filter function

Tags: python

I have a nested list as below:

```
students = [['Jagan', 65.5], ['Kiran', 55.45], ['Maddy', 47.2], ['Harsha', 75.0], ['Pavy', 55.45]]
```

I am trying to figure out the second lowest scorer for which I am using the function below to find out the second lowest number first,

```
def second_lowest(l):
small, second_small = float('inf'), float('inf')
for number in l:
    if number[1] <= small:
        small, second_small = number[1], small
    elif number[1] < second_small:
        second_small = number[1]
return second_small
```

After which I am using a lambda function as below to filter out the name of the second lowest scorer,

```
sl = second_lowest(students)
names = filter(lambda x: x[0] if (x[1] == sl) else None, students)
print names
```

I am expecting the output should be only names as I am using x[0] in the equation but I am getting whole list as shown below:

```
[['Kiran', 55.45], ['Pavy', 55.45]]
```

Comment: The function passed to filter is the predicate. Its return value decides what elements of the original sequence pass the filter. It should basically return True or False, but any truthy value will do, such as your non-empty strings vs. None. You'll have to map for example `itemgetter(0)` over the results, or use a list comprehension after filtering.

Comment: Any particular reason not to just use O(nlogn) sort instead of custom O(n) function? (There certainly _can_ be very good reasons, but maybe this is just unnecessary micro-optimization.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter() function works a bit different, it should return True or False for each item and only True one will be in the output, so you have to do it in a such way:

```
names = filter(lambda x: x[1] == sl, students)
```

to get only names you should use another lambda over it

```
names = map(labmda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] == sl, students))
```

or just one map() instead of filter(), but in that case, you'll get a list fill with None's

```
names = map(lambda x: x[0] if (x[1] == sl) else None, students)
```

Comment: Or use a list comprehension: `names = [n for (n, s) in students if s == s1]`, particularly since `map` and `filter` will behave differently in Python 3.